# Test Android Facebook Login before uploading to Google Play Store

Tags: android, facebook, google-play, facebook-login

I am developing an Android app wherein I'm doing Facebook Login Integration. Currently, I haven't uploaded it to Play Store yet. This will be my first app to upload in the Play Store. But I'm having a problem with testing Facebook Login in Android.

The problem is filling up profile for Android in Facebook Developer. I have generated a Facebook hash key using `debug.keystore`. I filled up the package name and other details to my Facebook test app as follow.

[image]

```
Package name does not exist yet on Google Playstore.
```

I click save button. It alerted me as follows.

[image]

As you can see, it says you can ignore it. What I thought it can be tested even if the package does not exist on Play Store as it is test app. I used that package name.

After it is saved, it auto ignores the hash key. Then I run my app and clicked login button. My app is redirected to Facebook and it is showing error. The error is:

```
hash key is not generated for current package name
```

It is asking me to generate hash key. What I can think is hash key is removed when I click save button in Facebook developer because there is no package name on Play Store.

Now I have to upload my app to Play Store. It may take too long. I have to wait for it finished. Then after approved, I also have to update the app on Play Store again.

What I want to know is if there is any way to test Facebook Login without uploading released APK on Play Store?

Comment: Are you sure the hash key you have is the right one for the package you're trying to test? How did you generate it?

Comment: I generated using keytool terminal using openssl.

Comment: So does not matter I uploaded apk on playstore or not? Can I develop facebook login in test mode?

Comment: Try the code method where you log the key hash to logcat. [Look Here](http://pastebin.com/MHuHSn0Y)

Comment: And no. You don't need to upload your apk to the play store to test out your app. That would be ridiculous.

Comment: Ah. I could set hash. Problem with my typo. But still having problem. When click faccebook login buton. I just showing loading progress circle. It does not even redirecting to Facebook. Then after a while, the circle disappears. No error is thrown. What is wrong please? I test on real device and logcat also showing nothing.

Comment: For hash key. I have to generate debug or release? Does debug also work please?

Comment: For hash key just copy that code into your activity's `onCreate` and see what it outputs to the log. For development it will be debug

Comment: Are you using your debug signing key in the app and have the hash key of the distribution key in the Facebook config?

Comment: I generated hash from debug signing key. Then I set that hash value in Facebook Developer settings. Debug signing key works to test Facebook Login?